# Can't connect on an SQL Server 2012 named instance on a second computer on the network

Tags: sql-server

Both computer have Windows 7 but i can't connect from one computer to the other where SQL Server 2012 Express is installed. EDIT: This is a local network.

Ive opened up the program on the firewall and enable sql browser service but i still can't connect.

I used the format "HOSTNAME\NAMEDINSTANCE".

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. The SQL Browser service isn't required in order to connect to a SQL instance over the network... and I wish people would stop thinking that it is. 2. Have you enabled any network protocols for the SQL instance? 3. How about giving us some details on what message, if any, that you get when trying to connect.

Comment: It say it can't connect. Error 26 Cannot localize the instance. I try to connect from visual studio 2012 using windows auth.

Comment: @joeqwerty The browser service is required if you try to use named instances. If you use the port number its not.

Comment: The SQL browser service is only required for a named instance if you don't specify the port for the named instance or if SQL Server is using dynamic ports. My point is that mucking about with the SQL browser service isn't the path I would take while troubleshooting a connectivity problem

Answer (score -1):

You can visit following articles for solution of your query :

[Connecting MSSQL from Another Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
[Connect to a SQL Server Named Instance](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2661/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-named-instance/)

Hope this helps you.